# Number of paths of length $4$

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph that look like the graph below. I need to show that between every pair of vertices there is at least a path of length $4$. I need also to find how many such as these paths is there between $a$ and $b?$

```
  c
 | \
 |  \
 a----b----e
 |   /
 |  /
  d
```

I know that I have to start by setting up a adjacency matrix, which is:

```
       0    1   1   1   0
       1    0   1   1   1
       1    1   0   0   0
       1    1   0   0   0
       0    1   0   0   0
```

But I am not sure how to continue here to answer the questions above.

Comment: I think the c at the right of the diagram should be labeled e. Then take the fourth power of the matrix, if all entries nonzero you're done, if some are zero take larger powers. For number of length 4 from a to b look at the entry in fourth power of matrix in row a column b.

Comment: true, it should be e , i edited the question. i have to take the fourth power of the matrix because i am have to find paths of length 4?

Comment: It's a little more involved in general, see my answer below (too long for a comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $k$th power of the adjacency matrix $A$ has its entry in row $i$ column $j$ the number of paths of length exactly $k$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j.$ This can be seen to work by seeing how matrix multiplication works for some specific adjacency matrices of not to large size and some moderate values of $k.$

So to show every vertex is connected to each other vertex by a path of length at least 4, to be complete one would look at the sequence $A^4,A^5,A^6,\cdots$ and see if some entry of at least one of these in position $(i,j)$ is positive. Of course you can stop if you ever get a single power 4th or higher of the matrix with all positive entries.

Note: as M. Vinay points out, the powers of the adjacency matrix have entries giving the number of walks, rather than paths, of a given length between the vertices.
Another note is it matters whether you want to make sure paths from a vertex to itself exist of length 4 or more, or do not require that. In the latter case you just don't need to consider the diagonal elements being 0 or positive in the above.

It seems likely in your example a relatively small power of $A$ at 4 or more power will have all positive entries, since the graph is connected.

Your other question is easier since you want the number of paths of length 4 between two specific vertices. So for that you only need look at $A^4$ and find the entry in the $(i,j)$ position, where $i,j$ are the specific vertices.

Comment: How about when multiplying the martices ? is it the normal Matrix multiplication? i mean the martices are huge , any trick to the multiplication fast and simple?

Comment: According to the usual definition, paths have distinct vertices (but walks, which are more general, need not). The $(i,j)$ entry of $A^k$ gives the number of walks of length $k$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$. 
You need to figure out all possible types of walks of length $4$ between two vertices, and then separate the paths from the non-paths (this is not too difficult).

Comment: @humble24 It's generally easy to multiply $(0,1)$ matrices. When you multiply by such a matrix on the left, you just have to look at each row (say $r$), then "select" the rows of the second matrix corresponding on the $1$s in the row $r$, and add them to obtain the corresponding row of the product. Also, in this case it's not cheating to use a computer to do the multiplication for you.

Comment: Hm, although with that definition of "path", there isn't a path of length $4$ between all the vertices. So I suppose the question actually means "walk" rather than "path".

Comment: Sure, But what to do if i get such question on exam , no calculator or computer allowed :(

Comment: @humble24 Like I said, it's not too difficult when you're multiplying by a $(0,1)$ matrix. A little practice and you'll be able to do it quickly.

Comment: alright thanks :). Just to be sure . if i need to find path of length of 5 . i have to look at $A^5$

Comment: @humble24 Yeah, only I'd call it a walk of length $5$. What is a "path" according to your definition?

Comment: by my definition, path is the way you can move in the graph

Comment: @humble24 Then your definition is same as the other definition of "walk" i.e. no need for distinct vertices or edges along the path.

Comment: alright thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the $4th$ power of your adjacency matrix and at every entry that you have a nonzero value, that is the number of 4 edges paths that you have between the vertices $i$ and $j$.